# URL Rewriting : not working on ONE single url

Tags: apache, url-rewriting

I'm trying to rewrite my URLs for an internal PHP application but it doesnt work on only ONE URL:

```
<a href='/device/' >Link text</a>
<a href='/brand/' >Link text</a>
```

.htaccess (found on google)

```
RewriteEngine on
Options -MultiViews

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /+[^\.]+$
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z/]+)?$    index.php?vars=$1 [NC,L]
```

Result clicking on links :

```
http://localhost/index.php/?vars=device/
http://localhost/brand/
```

And both works. Any ideas ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I spotted that it happened on every URL after a change on .htaccess
Undo the chance would not change anything.
Empty browser cache and history, refresh the page and it works again.